# Postgresql regexp_matches syntax not working as expected

Tags: regex, postgresql

I use the Postgres **regexp_matches** function to extract numbers.

The regular expression I use is

```
4([\s\-\/\.]*?0){3}([\s\-\/\.]*?[12]){1}([\s\-\/\.]*?\d){4}
```

If I use a tool like https://regexr.com/ to verify if it's working and I apply the following test set

```
4-0001-1234
5-2342-2344
499999999
4-0001-1234 4.0001.12344  4-0-0-0-1-1234
```

I get the expected extraction result:

```
4-0001-1234
4-0001-1234
4.0001.1234
4-0-0-0-1-1234
```

However, if I use the same expression in Postgresql, it does work well:

```
SELECT unnest(regexp_matches('4-0001-1234', '4([\s\-\/\.]*?0){3}([\s\-\/\.]*?[12]){1}([\s\-\/\.]*?\d){4}', 'g'));
```

Result:

```
0
1
4
```

What I suspect is, that it has to do with the greediness and/or that the quantifiers like *{3}* are not applied in the right way. Or it uses the Posix standard for regular expressions, which always seem to differ a little bit from the Java Syntax.

Any suggestions why it is not working and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "Java syntax"?

Comment: `{1}` is pointless.

Comment: regexr shows exactly the same results if you hover over the match: "*group #1: 0; group #2: 1; group #3: 4*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`regexp_matches(string text, pattern text [, flags text])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function returns the captured values:

> Return all captured substrings resulting from matching a POSIX regular expression against the string.

You may fix the expression using non-capturing groups:

```
SELECT unnest(regexp_matches('4-0001-1234 4.0001.12344  4-0-0-0-1-1234', '4(?:[\s/.-]*0){3}(?:[\s/.-]*[12])(?:[\s/.-]*\d){4}', 'g'));
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/BRH13212).

[image]

BTW, you do not need to escape `-` when it is at the start/end of the bracket expression, and there is no need to escape neither `/` nor `.` there. I also suggest removing `{1}` as `a` = `a{1}` in any regex supporting limiting quantifiers.